# Different document.domain on same url

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, frame, same-origin-policy

I'm working on a chrome plugin that creates an iframe inside a page WITH THE SAME URL of the original page (adding only an hash).

for example, i launch my plugin on "www.example.com/index.php". The plugin adds in this page an iframe called "secondaryFrame" with a src="www.example.com/index.php#myhash".

From the parent frame i can access the "secondaryFrame".contentWindow.document as they have both the same document.domain "example.com"

The problem is that on a few number of sites the two document.domain are different:
parent frame: "example.com"
secondary frame: "www.example.com"
How is it possible? Both frames have the same url... why one of the document.domain use also the "www" part?
In this case i can't access the contentWindow of the secondary frame and it's a problem.. have you got a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you're obtaining the URLs which you use for your parent and secondary frame.  Generally, within the domain name system as it's applied to websites, "www.domain.name" is simply an alias for "domian.name", and vice versa, and stripping off the "www." in your code will probably access exactly the same content and satisfy the domain name restrictions in JS.

There's no guarantee of this, of course, and "http://www.domain.name" could be made to work entirely differently from "http://domain.name".  It's just that this naming convention has been common practice for many years.